# Urls with hiding query parameters not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Here my htaccess file is :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(^.*)\.gautam.com
```

And at the end of the file I have writen :

```
RewriteRule ^jobs/([^\.]+)$ jobs?type=$1 [NC,L]
```

to change my url from :

```
gautam.com/jobs?type=what ever
```

to this

```
gautam.com/jobs/what ever
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule looks fine but it should be moved above your other rewrite rules.

The following is superseding it because it comes first and `/jobs/whatever` probably meets the `!-f` and `!-d` criteria.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: What are you getting? I copied your rule and it worked fine for me.

Comment: It is working but for css I have given paths like "href="css/style.css" is getting wrokng url like http://gautam.com/jobs/css/style.css

Comment: You need to fix your paths in this case.  `href="css/style.css"` is relative and when your URL looks like `/jobs/xxx` the browser will be trying to load `jobs/xxx/css/style.css`.  At the very least, just change all your script and stylesheets to be absolute (`href="/css/style.css"`).

Comment: I have around 200 files, need to change in all I guess. Is there any other way?

Comment: Yikes, each file has the paths hard coded (no common header/footer/layout file to control everything)?  You can add a `<base href="/">` tag in the `<head>` of your file, but this has to be done in each file so I don't think it really is any better.  You can use perl or sed to do inline search and replace on all the files to do this for you, some searches will give you help on that.

Comment: I have used this `RewriteRule ^jobs/([^\.]+)$ jobs?type=$1 [NC,L]` and working fine if I have alphabets,numbers but if I got `special characters` it is not working. I'm `urlencode` of each parameter and passing to url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115427/discussion-between-drew010-and-gautam3164).

Comment: Try `RewriteRule ^jobs/(.*)$ jobs?type=$1 [NC,L]` instead to match all characters.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
RewriteRule ^jobs/([0-9]+) jobs.php?type=$1
```

and if you want to pass 2 parameters:

```
RewriteRule ^jobs/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) jobs.php?id=$1&&message=$2
```

Comment: But its not redirecting, sitll showing same url. Even I'm not able to access like `http://gautam.com/jobs/Medical+Jobs`

Comment: is jobs a file like .php or a folder? and the parametters are they words or numbers?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^jobs/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) jobs.php?type=$1`

Comment: It is working but for css I have given paths like "href="css/style.css" is getting wrokng url like `http://gautam.com/jobs/css/style.css`